# Access JSON Property from Nested Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a nested JSON object below returned as responseObject which I would like to access the property "message".

```
 var reponseObject = 
    "{
        "DynamicBundleResponse":
            {
                "status":"204",
                "message":"Business error has occured",
                "PropertyChanged":null
            }
    }"
```

I have tried to the following as per some responses on the internet but both returning undefined:

1. responseObject.DynamicBundleResponse.message
2. responseObject["DynamicBundleResponse"].message

   I have tried to the following as per some responses on the internet but both returning undefined:
3. responseObject.DynamicBundleResponse.message
4. responseObject["DynamicBundleResponse"].message

   var reponseObject = 
       "{
           "DynamicBundleResponse":
               {
                   "status":"204",
                   "message":"Business error has occured",
                   "PropertyChanged":null
               }
       }"

   ```
       var res = responseObject.DynamicBundleResponse.message //returning undefined
   ```

Getting undefined.

Comment: Because your `responseObject` is actually a string and not an `object`. You have to parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var reponseString = `{
    "DynamicBundleResponse":
        {
            "status":"204",
            "message":"Business error has occured",
            "PropertyChanged":null
        }
}`;

var responseObject = JSON.parse(responseString);
var message = responseObject.DynamicBundleResponse.message;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.` dot notation to access the properties. The object is in a string format(which is also using `""` incorrectly). Parse the object using `JSON.parse(object)` and then proceed using same steps

```js
var reponseObject = 
    {
        "DynamicBundleResponse":
            {
                "status":"204",
                "message":"Business error has occured",
                "PropertyChanged":null
            }
    }
    console.log(reponseObject.DynamicBundleResponse.message)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to parse the string into an object:

```js
var reponseObject =  '{"DynamicBundleResponse": { "status": "204", "message": "Business error has occured", "PropertyChanged": null } }'

const asObject = JSON.parse(reponseObject);

console.dir(asObject.DynamicBundleResponse.message)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few things to note here:

1. **Spelling Mistake:** The variable name at the time of declaration is different than the variable used to access  the object. Use same variable name at both the places.
2. **Double quotes** are used before and after the braces, it looks like a string, but if used inside code, will give error - `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`. Just remove the first and last double quotation marks and it becomes an object.

Now you can access the 'message' property by both the ways you were trying.

```
var responseObject = { "DynamicBundleResponse": { "status":"204", "message":"Business error has occured", "PropertyChanged":null } };
console.log(responseObject.DynamicBundleResponse.message);
console.log(responseObject["DynamicBundleResponse"].message);
```

**Note:** If you want to continue declaring the object as a string, do so by using single quotation marks to avoid syntax error and then parse the string to JSON as mentioned in other answers.

Hope this helps!